# two relation values in one column array yii gridview

Tags: yii

how to display two relation values in one column array values  gridview yii

in my model code with relation

```
$criteria->compare('exp.ExperienceYear',$this->Experience, true);
 $criteria->compare('exp.ExperienceMonth',$this->Experience, true);
```

in my gridview column array code

```
array( 
                 'name' => 'Experience',
                 'type' => 'raw',
                    'value'=> '(empty($data->exp->ExperienceYear))? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->exp->ExperienceYear.\'-\'.(empty($data->exp->ExperienceMonth))? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->exp->ExperienceMonth' ,

           ),
```

its  not displaying two relation values in one field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem here is that you should add extra brackets around your ternary operations. They have a very "annoying" way of [resulting in unexpected behavior](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) with more than one

```
array( 
   'name' => 'Experience',
   'type' => 'raw',
   'value'=> '(empty($data->exp->ExperienceYear)? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->exp->ExperienceYear.\'-\') . (empty($data->exp->ExperienceMonth)? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->exp->ExperienceMonth)' ,
),
```

As you can see, I've moved the closing bracket of your empty condition to the end of each ternary operation to fully enclose it. IMO that should solve the problem.